# discord.js renaming channel name in a certain layout

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make it so when I carry out a command, it'll rename the current channel's name in a certain layout.

The wanted command is `.a1 (insert wanted channel name)`

An example of a "layout" would be: `a123-(insert wanted channel name)-b123`. The a123 and b123 part will stay constant, only the middle part can be changed.

This is what I've been using so far to rename channels:

```
    message.channel.setName(`a123・${message.author.username}`)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may simply get the user arguments like so:

```js
const prefix = "!";
const  args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(' ');
```

Now further we would just use the user input like so:

```js
message.channel.setName("a123-" + args.join("-") + "b123");
```

Please note that your definition of `prefix` and `message` may vary as per your code, message event parameter and definition of prefix, so I suggest to grasp the concept of my answer rather than copy pasting.